# Which MySQL shows CPU usage?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, monitoring

I am monitoring MySQL server using phpMyAdmin [Status => Monitor] function. And it shows a number of useful graphs.

[image: phpMyAdmin Status Monitor]

**Which variables (or which mechanism) is phpMyAdmin using to pull this data?**

ps. I was wondering if it is calling `SHOW STATUS` query?   But when I look through a bunch of variables resulting from `SHOW STATUS` I cannot spot anything related neither to CPU, memory or not even active connnections...

[image]

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner.pl report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server workload tuning analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Some guesses.  Some things come from `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` (highlighted and with initial caps, below); some from elsewhere.

Questions:  Status `Questions` or `Queries`.  The latter seems to include statements inside Stored routines.

Connections:  Not `Connections` since that continues to grow.  Probably not `Threads_running` since that should be very small.

Processes:  Perhaps from the OS.  Are you using Windows?

Traffic:  `Bytes_sent/received`.  (Not very useful)

CPU Usage:  The OS.  That is *high*.  You have some slow queries and/or poor indexing.  See the slowlog (more below).

System Memory:  The OS.  See `top` or whatever Windows has.  Sounds like there is room to increase some settings.  Do you have 6MB of RAM?

Swap:  From the OS.  No swapping is Good.

Slow queries:  `Slow_queries`.  0 is good ...IF... you have a reasonable value for `long_query_time`, which defaults to 10 seconds.  Change it to 1.

Key reads:  Maybe `Key_reads`, which applies only to MyISAM.  Are you using that engine?  Maybe `Handler_read_key`, which applies to all engines, but is not useful by itself.

The graphs are pretty, but mostly useless.

I may be able to give you about 20 tips from the full set of VARIABLES and GLOBAL STATUS, plus tips from the slowlog, once you make use of it:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis

Comment: Than you this sheds some light on those variables. This is CentOS on a shared hosting. (as it is shared hosting I have limited access to MySQL and thus trying to find ways to monitor it..)